# replacing return types of class methods with inherited class

Tags: python

I'm extending the datetime object because I would like to override the **str** method.

```
class MyDatetime(datetime.datetime):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

problem, is that whenever I start adding and subtracting timedeltas, I get back datetimes and not MyDatetimes.  I could include a constructor for a MyDatetime from a datetime and then override the `__add__` and `__sub__` methods as well, but there could be others, and it just seems like there should be some easy way to deal with this... Any suggestions?

Comment: No, that's exactly the way you have to deal with it; unless the superclass methods are written to use e.g. `type(self)` instead of the name of the class, any inherited methods that return new instances will return instances of the class they've inherited from.

Comment: You are experiencing [a bug in python](http://bugs.python.org/issue2267). There is no easy way to handle it, other than overriding every method.

Comment: not worth it.  I'll figure out something else.  =c)

Comment: also, ppperry, your comment is my vote for best answer, if it were an answer...

Comment: also, @jonrsharpe, the `type(self)` thing is genius.  Gonna keep that in mind for my own future classes.

Comment: @ppperry That's not a bug. You are linking a bug *report* which is *closed*. And many types behave that way, so the whole language would be buggy in this regard from the very beginning.

Comment: @BlackJack closed as won't fix. It **is** a bug, but one which the maintainers of python declined to fix.

Comment: It isn't a bug but a design decision. No matter how hard you think/wish it were a bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way in your situation - you'll have to override all mathematical magic methods if you want to cover all possible situations.

There's a comprehensive list of mathematical magic methods in Python documentation:

> https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

At least the code for those methods will be similar enough so you should be able to create them by lots of copy&paste with minor modifications.